# How to query for the table names list of a specific database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I simply need a mysql/sql query to get the names of all tables of a specific database.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query for My sql:

**show tables;**

Answer (score 0):

Found by myself:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your db name'
```

Comment: Or `SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your db name'`?

Comment: @jarlh ... AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' (to exclude any views)

Comment: If that's what OP wants... (A view is a table, but not a base table.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query for MSSql:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' +  TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query after switching specific database

> **show tables;**

otherwise you can use

> SELECT TABLE_NAME
>   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
>   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db name'